# How do I open/create a menu in WPf with Material Design

Tags: wpf, menu, material-design, drawer

So I´m using Material Design and Caliburn micro.
I want to get used to Material Design and im new to WPF. But i have to use both because of work.
I want to have a Colorzone in the top of my form.

```
<materialDesign:ColorZone 
Mode="PrimaryLight"
Grid.Row="0"
Grid.Column="0"
Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
Padding="16">
    <StackPanel
    Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ToggleButton
        Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignHamburgerToggleButton}">               
        </ToggleButton>
        <TextBlock
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="16 0 0 0">
        Material Design In XAML Toolkit
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</materialDesign:ColorZone>
```

I got the hamburger button on the right and when i start it the Animation works but how do i open a drawer or a menu when the button is clicked and how do i close it when it is pressed again.
Where do i write the code what the button does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found an Answer:

```
<materialDesign:ColorZone 
Mode="PrimaryLight"
Grid.Row="0"
Grid.Column="0"
Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
Padding="16">
    <StackPanel
    Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ToggleButton

        Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DrawerHost.OpenDrawerCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{x:Static Dock.Left}"

        Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignHamburgerToggleButton}">               
        </ToggleButton>
        <TextBlock
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="16 0 0 0">
        Material Design In XAML Toolkit
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</materialDesign:ColorZone>
```

You have to Add the Command and a CommandParameter for the Hamburger Button.

Now we just need a Drawer that we can open:

```
<materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>
    <StackPanel Margin="16" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Button 
            Margin="25,10,25,10"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            cal:Message.Attach="DoCoolStuff()"

            Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DrawerHost.CloseDrawerCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{x:Static Dock.Left}">

            BlaBlaBlaYour Button Text here
        </Button>
        <Button    
    </StackPanel>
</materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>
```

So now we got a Menubar and A Drawer but they wont work until we write the them both into the following:

```
<materialDesign:DrawerHost Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}" 
Panel.ZIndex="1">

<materialDesign:ColorZone...>
<materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent...>

</materialDesign:DrawerHost>
```

It is important that we give the DrawerHost Panel.ZIndex = 1 because when you have a button where the Drawer should open the button will be in the Foreground but now the Drawer will be.

And thats it, now we have a menubar with a Hamburgerbutton that opens a drawer.
A tip for the Button i Added it does not need the Command and the commandparameter but it help when you want to close the drawer when a button is pressed.

I hope i could help somebody

Answer (score 0):

maybe this question old, however.
this what i used for Navigation between Pages, i use `Caliburn.Micro.4.0.212` and `MaterialDesignThemes.4.9.0`
This my `ShellView.xaml`

```
<Window>
    <materialDesign:DrawerHost Grid.Row="0" IsLeftDrawerOpen="{Binding ElementName=MenuToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <materialDesign:ColorZone Grid.Row="0" Mode="PrimaryMid">
                <ToggleButton
                    x:Name="MenuToggleButton"
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    IsChecked="False"
                    Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignHamburgerToggleButton}" />
            </materialDesign:ColorZone>
            <ContentControl
                x:Name="ActiveItem"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="10" />
        </Grid>
        <materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <DockPanel
                    Name="NavigationWidth"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Width="200">
                    <ToggleButton
                        Margin="5"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MenuToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}"
                        Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignHamburgerToggleButton}" />
                </DockPanel>
                <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Button
                        Width="{Binding ElementName=NavigationWidth, Path=Width}"
                        Height="50"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        cal:Message.Attach="Navigation('Home')"
                        Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBackground}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDarkBackground}"
                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedLightButton}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon
                                Width="30"
                                Height="30"
                                Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Kind="HomeOutline" />
                            <Label
                                Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Content="Home"
                                FontSize="18" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        Width="{Binding ElementName=NavigationWidth, Path=Width}"
                        Height="50"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        cal:Message.Attach="Navigation('Settings')"
                        Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBackground}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDarkBackground}"
                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedLightButton}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon
                                Width="30"
                                Height="30"
                                Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Kind="SettingsOutline" />
                            <Label
                                Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Content="Settings"
                                FontSize="18" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        Width="{Binding ElementName=NavigationWidth, Path=Width}"
                        Height="50"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        cal:Message.Attach="Navigation('About')"
                        Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBackground}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDarkBackground}"
                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedLightButton}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon
                                Width="30"
                                Height="30"
                                Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Kind="AboutOutline" />
                            <Label
                                Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Content="About"
                                FontSize="18" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>
    </materialDesign:DrawerHost>
</Window>
```

and this `ShellViewModel`

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>
{
    protected async override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        base.OnViewLoaded(view);
        await ActivateItemAsync(new HomeViewModel());
    }
    public async Task Navigation(string pageName)
    {
        switch (pageName)
        {
            case ("Home"):
                await ActivateItemAsync(new HomeViewModel());
                break;
            case ("Settings"):
                await ActivateItemAsync(new SettingViewModel());
                break;
            case ("About"):
                await ActivateItemAsync(new AboutViewModel());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

i cant post images on stackoverflow because i don't have reputations so if you wanna see the result i upload gif on my drive:
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AzmBzQ8sxzx7_xgSvekxBlbsdefrLz6x/view?usp=drive_link)

### Notes

> 1 - be sure of names because `caliburn.micro` sensitive of names,Good luck.

> 2 - And Create a Template So when create a new project you dont need to write all this code again